# Failed to start QThread when using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: multithreading, qt, c++11, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm currently trying to make a software that downloads a lot of files from Google Drive. Downloading is currently not a problem.

Nevertheless, I encounter an issue when launching 500+ simultaneous downloads. I use a slightly modified version of this tutorial : https://wiki.qt.io/Download_Data_from_URL.

Here is the .h file :

```
class FileDownloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FileDownloader(QUrl url, QObject *parent = 0, int number = 0);
    QByteArray downloadedData() const;
    void launchNewDownload(QUrl url);
    QByteArray m_DownloadedData;
    QNetworkReply* reply;

    static QNetworkAccessManager *m_WebCtrl;

signals:
    void downloaded();

private slots:
    void fileDownloaded(QNetworkReply* pReply);
};
```

And here is the .cpp file :

```
QNetworkAccessManager* FileDownloader::m_WebCtrl = nullptr;

FileDownloader::FileDownloader(QUrl url, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    if (m_WebCtrl == nullptr) {
        m_WebCtrl = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    }
    connect(m_WebCtrl, SIGNAL (finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT (fileDownloaded(QNetworkReply*)));

    launchNewDownload(url);
}

void FileDownloader::launchNewDownload(QUrl url) {
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    this->reply = m_WebCtrl->get(request);
}

void FileDownloader::fileDownloaded(QNetworkReply* pReply) {
    m_DownloadedData = pReply->readAll();

    //emit a signal
    pReply->deleteLater();
    emit downloaded();
}

QByteArray FileDownloader::downloadedData() const {
    return m_DownloadedData;
}
```

The issue is "QThread::start: Failed to create thread ()" when reaching about the 500th download. I tried to limit the number of downloads which run at the same time - but I always get the same issue. Besides, I tried to delete every downloader when finishing its task - it did nothing else than crashing the program ;)

I think that it is coming from the number of threads allowed for an only process, but I'm not able to solve it !

Does anyone have an idea that could help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: Are you starting your own threads to run requests? Or do you have multiple instances of `QNetworkAccessManager` (maybe one for each request)? You don't need both of the above for your objective. **You just need one instance of `QNetworkAccessManager` and your main thread** (and nothing more). Use the asynchronous API `QNetworkAccessManager` provides. Let Qt handle low level details of parallelizing requests when possible and You should be fine.

Comment: I have multiple instances of QNetworkAccessManager, but only the main thread.
When I try to use only one (static) instance of QNetworkAccessManager, my program has a strange behavior. It doesn't work anymore, files are instantly downloaded without any content... And there is much more files than expected !

Comment: **You need to add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question to be answerable.** You must be doing something wrong in your code for that to happen.

Comment: Sorry for the MCVE, I'm not used with StackOverFlow !
Here are the files, I hope there are clear enough.

Comment: I think I found where was the issue. When I connect the signal to the slot, it disconnects the previous slot. I'll try to fix it and I hope it will work then. Thanks !

Comment: *" When I connect the signal to the slot, it disconnects the previous slot."*. No, this is not true. When connecting new signals/slots, Qt never disconnects old slots. You can even connect the same signal/slot pair more than once (this will result in the slot being called many times whenever the signal is emitted).

Comment: I thought it disconnected it because I had some strange behaviors a few months ago. It was when i learned Qt, I surely did some other error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QNetworkAccessManager::finished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) signal is documented to be *emitted whenever a pending network reply is finished*.

This means that if the `QNetworkAccessManager` is used to run multiple requests at a time (and this is [perfectly normal usage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details)). `finished` signal will be emitted once for every request. Since you have a shared instance of `QNetworkAccessManager` between your `FileDownloader` objects, the `finished` signal gets emitted for every `get` call you have made. So, all the `FileDownloader` objects get a `finished` signal as soon as the first `FileDownloader` finishes downloading.

Instead of using `QNetworkAccessManager::finished`, you can use [`QNetworkReply::finished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#finished) to avoid mixing up signals. Here is an example implementation:

```
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QtWidgets>

class FileDownloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    //using constructor injection instead of a static QNetworkAccessManager pointer
    //This allows to share the same QNetworkAccessManager
    //object with other classes utilizing network access
    QNetworkAccessManager* m_nam;
    QNetworkReply* m_reply;
    QByteArray m_downloadedData;

public:
    explicit FileDownloader(QUrl imageUrl, QNetworkAccessManager* nam,
                            QObject* parent= nullptr)
        :QObject(parent), m_nam(nam)
    {
        QNetworkRequest request(imageUrl);
        m_reply = m_nam->get(request);
        connect(m_reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &FileDownloader::fileDownloaded);
    }
    ~FileDownloader() = default;

    QByteArray downloadedData()const{return m_downloadedData;}

signals:
    void downloaded();
private slots:
    void fileDownloaded(){
        m_downloadedData= m_reply->readAll();
        m_reply->deleteLater();
        emit downloaded();
    }
};

//sample usage
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QNetworkAccessManager nam;
    FileDownloader fileDownloader(QUrl("http://i.imgur.com/Rt8fqpt.png"), &nam);
    QLabel label;
    label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    label.setText("Downloading. . .");
    label.setMinimumSize(640, 480);
    label.show();
    QObject::connect(&fileDownloader, &FileDownloader::downloaded, [&]{
        QPixmap pixmap;
        pixmap.loadFromData(fileDownloader.downloadedData());
        label.setPixmap(pixmap);
    });

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

---

<sup>If you are using this method to download large files, consider having a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42580585/2666212).</sup>

Comment: Thanks, it worked ! I didn't know QNetworkReply had a signal "finished"...

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to uses a [QThreadPool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html). You simply feed it tasks (QRunnable) and it will handle the number of threads and the task queue for you.

However in your case this is not perfect because you will be limiting the number of simultaneous downloads to the number of threads created by QThreadPool (generally the number of CPU core you have).

To overcome this you will have to handle the QThread yourself and not use QThreadPool. You would create a small number of thread (see `QThread::idealThreadCount()`) and run multiple `FileDownloader` on each QThread.

Comment: **Please note that there is generally no need to use a `QThreadPool` when using `QNetworkAccessManager`.** From the docs: *" QNetworkAccessManager queues the requests it receives. The number of requests executed in parallel is dependent on the protocol. Currently, for the HTTP protocol on desktop platforms, 6 requests are executed in parallel for one host/port combination."*. `QNetworkAccessManager` already handles these low level details, It is internally designed to suit the way QtWebKit works, see [here](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/04/29/threaded-http-inside-qnetworkaccessmanager/).